# How to Create a Directory in a Plugin Folder?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, php

I am creating a plugin in WordPress Version 3.4.2. When the administrator submits a form, a new folder is created inside my plugin directory and a file saved in this new folder.

But it gives me the following error:

```
error : The file has not been created 

$dir = plugins_url()."/folder-name/;
```

The above code returns the following path:

```
http://localhost/website/wp-content/plugins/abc/folder-name

mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use the plugin directory to store new files.

- During an update the plugin directory will be erased by WordPress. And all files in it too.
- The plugin directory might be read-only in some setups (I do that always).

Use the [regular uploads directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) for that.

And `0777` is never a good idea. Write access for everyone is probably not what your users want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [plugin_dir_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) in your plugin to get current path in file system.

```
define( 'YOURPLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
```

code of the function itself

```
/**
 * Gets the filesystem directory path (with trailing slash) for the plugin __FILE__ passed in
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Plugin
 * @since 2.8
 *
 * @param string $file The filename of the plugin (__FILE__)
 * @return string the filesystem path of the directory that contains the plugin
 */
    function plugin_dir_path( $file ) {
        return trailingslashit( dirname( $file ) );
    }
```

Comment: my path is correct, there is no problem with `plugins_url()` but `mkdir()` not creating the folder

Comment: Do you understand that You tring to create directory on a file system with argument of URL? You need PATH of file which you use with plugin_dir_path help. defining a constant will make less code just typing `$dir = YOURPLUGIN_PATH."/folder-name/; ` (in case if you had define your constant)..

Answer (score 2):

In short: you need a PATH, not an URL

In long: Do **not** create directories in your plugin folder (see Toscho's answer). Use the constant ´WP_CONTENT_DIR´ for the path instead of `plugins_url()`. This will create the directory within ´wp-content´ (on a standrad installation). Maybe you will define a sub-directory where you creates the directories.

```
define( 'STORING_DIRECTORY', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/my_plugin_storing_directory/' );
$dir = STORING_DIRECTORY . '/folder-name/';
```

Maybe you want to use the upload directory to create your directories. Than you should use `wp_upload_dir()` to get the path.

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/folder-name/';
```

Comment: The upload directories are the only ones with guaranteed write access. You should not expect write access for `WP_CONTENT_DIR`.