# File permissions for wp-minify plugin

Tags: plugins, security, cache

I am worried on installing [Wp-Minify plugin](http://omninoggin.com/wordpress-plugins/wp-minify-wordpress-plugin/). But it needs 777 permission for the cache directory located inside wp-uploads directory. Isn't it a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

toscho is right.
So you could probably give a try to another plugin. The [Better Wordpress Minify](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bwp-minify/).

This one also uses a folder inside the plugin's folder, BUT. You can change the folder and place it elsewhere. Please have a look at [Advanced Customization](http://betterwp.net/wordpress-plugins/bwp-minify/#advanced_customization).
[screenshot http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bwp-minify/screenshot-1.gif](http://s.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bwp-minify/screenshot-1.gif)

We have been using it without a problem.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn’t need `777`. The author recommends it, but you don’t have to follow that. The [usual file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) should be good.

The real problem: the plugin wants to write into its own plugin directory.

```
var $cache_location = 'wp-content/plugins/wp-minify/cache/';
```

[This is bad.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73887/73) After each update, the whole cache will be gone, and if you don’t allow write access to the plugin directory by default, the plugin will just not work.

And a hard codet `wp-content` directory is a rather bold assumption. It should use the constant `WP_CONTENT_DIR`, because the real name and path of that directory is configurable.